# How should can I set up a machine dedicated only to running ZynAddSubFx syntheziser?

Tags: linux, system-installation, audio, small-distribution, distributions

I'd like to set up a Linux machine dedicated only to run the soft synth ZynAddSubFx or Yoshimi (and receive midi data for ditto). The synth should start automatically when I switch on the power.

I'd like a distro that is aimed at sound with not so much stuff running in the background, but it should also be as minimal as possible. The last said because I've found that AV Linux, Ubuntu Studio and other media linux distros tend to be cluttered with pre-installed programs. All I need is to be able to run Jack and the synth. I don't want tons of pre-installed other programs.

The CPU is an Intel Pentium 4.

How can I install this machine?

Comment: I would use gentoo and add only these pieces to the box which I like. But this is obviously opinion-based question/answer, and probably will be closed.

Comment: Yes, you're right that it looks like it's a question about which distro I should use (I changed the wording in the headline). The question was intended to be much wider i e: how to achieve the system I desire. Well, let's see if anyone has some good thoughs.